# mongodb add an element to array of document by condition

Tags: mongodb

My document structure:

```
 "_id" : ObjectId("55e07b14bd1f3334f4d439ca"),
        "created" : ISODate("2015-08-28T15:15:32.251Z"),
        "userId" : 4790,
        "p2l" : [ 
            {
                "listId" : 31608,
                "status" : 25,
                "subscriptionDate" : ISODate("2015-09-16T12:33:03.893Z")
            },
            ...
        ]
```

I need find all documents where `p2l.listId==value` and then add to the `p2l` array a new document containing the same `p2l.status`, but with new `listId` and `subscriptionDate` values.

```
The example for finding this element:

        db.Profiles.find({ 
            "userId" : 4790, 
            "p2l" : { "$elemMatch" : { "listId" : { "$in" : [31617, 31614] } } } 
        })
```

How can I do an update then? I think it should be in the one query.
    I use C# Mongo Driver 2.0.
    For example:
    I have

```
"_id" : ObjectId("55e07b14bd1f3334f4d439ca"),
            "created" : ISODate("2015-08-28T15:15:32.251Z"),
            "userId" : 4790,
            "p2l" : [ 
                {
                    "listId" : 31608,
                    "status" : 25,
                    "subscriptionDate" : ISODate("2015-09-16T12:33:03.893Z")
                },
                ...
            ]
```

I need

```
     "_id" : ObjectId("55e07b14bd1f3334f4d439ca"),
            "created" : ISODate("2015-08-28T15:15:32.251Z"),
            "userId" : 4790,
            "p2l" : [ 
                {
                    "listId" : 31608,
                    "status" : 25,
                    "subscriptionDate" : ISODate("2015-09-16T12:33:03.893Z")
                }, 
                {
                    "listId" : 31615,
                    "status" : 25,
                    "subscriptionDate" : ISODate("2015-09-17T14:35:13.855Z")
                },
                ...
            ]
```

I find document, where userId=4790 and p2l.listId=31608, and then, add to this p2l new item with new listId = 31615 and subscriptionDate = 'ISODate("2015-09-17T14:35:13.855Z")', but old p2l.status = 25

Comment: You want to set the `status` of the new array object to equal the `status` of the other objects' `status` in the array? Will the `status` value always be the same for each object in the `p2l` array?

Comment: It's not very clear what you are asking here. Possibly something about inserting not existing array members by "listId" not found in a supplied list? At any rate, no update operation ( with the exception of things like `$inc` ) can reference the existing value of a document property in any way when setting another property. If you need to base parts of your update on existing values then you need a copy of the document already. It also does not make any sense to copy a property such as "status" to all array members. If it's always the same, then make it a property of the parent instead.

Answer (score 0):

Update it with `$push` operator

```
db.Profiles.update({ 
    "userId" : 4790, 
    "p2l" : { "$elemMatch" : { "listId" : { "$in" : [31617, 31614] } } } 
    },{'$push:{'p21':{..your new document..}}})
```

Comment: Yes, but I need to copy status to my new document from document, that was found by conditions.

Comment: I use c# Mongo Driver 2.0

Comment: You want to get the value from the document and use it in the doc to be pushed.I don't think it is possible to update like that using a single query (you updated the question?)